# What is the graph called?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to recreate graph shown here.[image]

I cannot find on excel, please help me understand the maths behind this graph.

Reference page # 9 
http://www.ten-inc.com/presentations/HP-State-of-Security-Operations-2014.pdf

Comment: It might help to expand your question a little.  Provide some context and a link to where the graph came from.  What do you want to illustrate in your graph?

Comment: I have updated the question.

Comment: Looks like a radar chart to me, try this: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Present-your-data-in-a-radar-chart-16e20279-eed4-43c2-9bf5-29ff9b10601d

Comment: An observation from an information presentation perspective, rather than an answer to what you asked: the value of a graph is that it provides a way to visualize information; humans are better at seeing/understanding visual patterns than a table of numbers.  This graph, and the way it was implemented, is close to worthless for that purpose; probably not even as useful as a simple bar chart.  If your question is just curiosity about an unusual graph, I commend you on your desire to learn.  If you are looking for a way to illustrate data, this would be low on my list of something to emulate.

Comment: Thanks fixer1234 for the critique but the representation is not for a science journal or thesis thus the reason for simplicity.

Comment: Does this question simply asks on "How to recreate the shown graph in a spreadsheet?". I've actually managed to recreate the graph similarly. I can answer this soon with detailed steps, if this question remains valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graph is called **radar chart** in Microsoft Excel or **net** in LibreOffice Calc. The graph shown in question seems to be the barebone or simple version of the chart, which consists of lines and points only (instead of filled).

To understand how the graph is created, we need to recreate the table beforehand. A graph is created from a table, which consists of at least single column against multiple rows or vice versa.

### Extracting data

In the question, I figured out that the "Average SOMM Score" is made from a table with single row and four columns. This can be explained as follows.

- There is only a single line that connects all data points with label, which means the table has a single row of numerical values (from top, clockwise: `1.63`,`1.66`,`1.52`, `1.81`).
- There are four titles at the edges of crossed-lines, which means the table has four columns of respective text (from top, clockwise: `Average of SOMM Level`, `Average of People`, `Average of Process`, `Average of Tech`).

I read the graph in clockwise direction, with respect to the [example instruction](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Present-your-data-in-a-radar-chart-16e20279-eed4-43c2-9bf5-29ff9b10601d) at Office Support (linked by @James). Clockwise direction seems to be the default in Microsoft Excel, but is reversed in LibreOffice Calc.

### Row or column

How to know which data (number or text) is row or column? Usually, the column will contain the common properties. Then, the row will be filled with values of incoming entries with respect to the common properties.

Another way to tell is by looking at which data (number or text) has more counts. The one with most counts will be placed in rows. But this can be misleading for the question case, in which available data (number) has only a single row. See also towards the end of this answer: **Understand the graph**

### Recreate the table

When creating a table, decide which data will appear as column and row. In the question case, the column will contain four data series of 'text' (thus four columns) and the row will contain one data series of 'number' (thus one row).

```
,Average of SOMM Level,Average of People,Average of Process,Average of Tech
Score,1.63,1.66,1.52,1.81
```

The text and numbers above are presented in CSV format instead of ASCII/HTML table, so that it may be easier to copy and paste later. When pasting into spreadsheet, right-click and select **Paste Special... > Unformatted text** (if applicable), then use **comma** for separator option.

The following screenshot shows the table after pasted into a spreadsheet in LibreOffice Calc.

[image: Table created in LibreOffice Calc]

### Recreate the graph

When creating a chart, the table need to be selected first, then go to **Insert** menu in the ribbon UI or menubar and select the chart menu. Steps to create a chart can be followed similarly in the example instruction as mentioned earlier.

The example instruction uses "filled radar", which is *not* the type used by the graph shown in question. Instead, select the chart type "radar with marker" in Microsoft Excel. This is known as "net" with "points and lines" in LibreOffice Calc.

The following screenshot shows the chart that has been created by default in LibreOffice Calc.

[image: Chart created in LibreOffice Calc]

It needs to be further customized to match the style of the graph shown in the question. Apply the following details and adjust if necessary.

> Title: `Average SOMM Score`
>
> > - Format Title > Font > Style: `Bold`
>
> Legend: Off
>
> X Axis (for data series of 'text')
>
> > - Scale - [x] Reverse direction (LibreOffice Calc only)
>
> Y Axis (for data series of 'number')
>
> > - Scale - Minimum: `0`
> > - Scale - Maximum: `5`
> > - Scale - Major interval: `1`
> > - Positioning - Interval Marks: Off (Deselect, if any)
>
> Data Labels: On (Insert, if none)
>
> > - Format Data Labels > `Outside` (Default)
> > - The label may be individually positioned to the left or right, if the label overlaps with the scale on axis
>
> Data Series (for the coloured line with data point)
>
> > - Format Data Series > Line > Icon: Round symbol (Selectable)
> > - Format Data Series > Line > Icon: Width/Height: `0.20 cm` (Adjustable)
> > - Format Data Series > Line > Transparency: `30%` (Adjustable)

Finally, resize chart area to be rectangular such that the title and the chart can fit without being cluttered by text inside. The chart after customization is shown in screenshot below.

[image: Chart customized in LibreOffice Calc]

### Understand the graph

For radar chart, it can be confusing to specify which are y-axis and x-axis. The line that connects all data points lies on the y-axis, and the crossed-line that contain text at the edges lies on the x-axis.

To demonstrate this, I have added more rows with numbers generated by `=RAND()` function. See the following screenshot how it turned out.

[image: Chart modded selection in LibreOffice Calc]

Notice that the screenshot was taken when editing the chart, in order to show clearly the original data series is part of y-axis. I had selected the corresponding line of first row data "Score", which represents the original data series used in the graph shown in the question.

**Remarks**: I don't have Microsoft Excel on my computer, so I used LibreOffice Calc (5.1) instead. The chart might be easier to do and more beautiful by default when created in Microsoft Excel.